# Image in bootstrap button change with the background color and not the button color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply a discord logo i founded on forkawesome (https://forkaweso.me/Fork-Awesome/icon/discord/)

I get a annoying issue with my code because i am trying to put the discord logo in a button but everytime the background change but not with the one of the button :

[image]

(i abused the size of the icon for showing what the exact issue is)

I also tried to use images instead at first with a .jpg but when i hover over the button the you can see the white background of the image

```html
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      <a href="scripts/discordLogin.php" class="btn btn-default">Discord Login <span class="fa fa-discord fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a>
    </form>
  </div>
```

If it would be possible to simply have the logo changing with the button color it would be awesome !

(jsfiddle as asked in the comments https://jsfiddle.net/9fmrwyje/ )

Comment: add your all HTML & CSS code here, like jsfiddle

Comment: we should see you css code as well

Comment: added the jsfiddle c:

Comment: If I understood you correctly you would like to change background color of the button with discord icon?

Comment: Not exactly i want the discord logo to have the same color as the button and not the same color as the background of the page (blue marine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that you wanted?

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #2a3752;
  color: #dcd1d1;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background-color: #2a3752;
}

.discord-logo-btn .fa-discord {
  background: #fff;
}

.discord-logo-btn:hover .fa-discord, .discord-logo-btn:focus .fa-discord  {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
  <title>Login</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fork-awesome@1.1.7/css/fork-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-gsmEoJAws/Kd3CjuOQzLie5Q3yshhvmo7YNtBG7aaEY=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/128.png" />
  <title>Login - JAPC Web management panel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
      <img src="images/128.png" alt="Join and play coop logo" align="middle">
    </div>
    <h3 class="text-center">JAPC Web Management panel login</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
      <a href="scripts/discordLogin.php" class="discord-logo-btn btn btn-default">Discord Login <span class="fa fa-discord fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your discord logo to be the same color as the button just change your code to this:

```
<a href="scripts/discordLogin.php" class="btn btn-default">Discord Login <span class="fa fa-discord fa-5x btn-default" aria-hidden="true" ></span></a>
```

Comment: Oh nice this worked ! but if i don't pass on the logo and only on the text the backgroud of the logo doesn't become grey as well but if i pass my mouse over the logo all the button becomes gray any idea how i could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No required custom CSS

add one Class on `container` with `login` & remove `*{` CSS add this css to `.login`

```
body
{
   background-color: #2a3752;
   font-family: arial;
}
.login{
   background-color: #2a3752;
   color: #dcd1d1;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/rofLg67y/7/